# Logging from the children of a supervisord subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, supervisord

My system is composed of a python application that is launched from supervisord. Let's call it `A`. `A` launches a subprocess `B` to do some of its task. Both `A` and `B` are coded in Python and use the standard `logging` module to output messages to the console.

The `stdout` and `stderr` of `A` are logged to a file specified in the supervisord configuration. This works like a charm. Now, I'd like to tunnel the `stdout` and `stderr` from `B` into the same file as in `A`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: It sounds like you should be able to use the same code for logging for `B` as you are using in `A`. Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. `B` inherits `A`'s standard streams by default.

If A's stdout is redirected to a file then `B`'s stdout automatically writes to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Python subprocess module provides facilities to read children stdout and stderr. You can capture them and send them to your logger. Below is a post-execution version which sends all output to logs after the child finishes. It is possible to do this also line-by-line and you can find examples reading subprocess stdout line-by-line in StackOverflow.

```
  worker = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  worker.wait()
  logger.debug("Subprocess %s stdout: %s", cmdline, worker.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks that drove me in the right direction. I was wondering if there wouldn't be a way to set the logging module in some magic way to bypass whatever treatment one may be doing to stdout/stderr of B and dump directly into the log file.

Comment: downvote. Do not use `stdout=PIPE` unless your read from the pipe otherwise the child may hang as soon as it fills its OS stdout pipe buffer (in your case, the child may hang while the parent is blocked on `worker.wait()` -- deadlock).